# Why cant I take the mean?

Tags: r, mean, factors

I have this data.

```
str(x1);
'data.frame':   163 obs. of  4 variables:
$ Cage    : int  4055 4055 4055 4055 4055 4055 4055 4055 4055 4055 ...
$ LineName: int  1 7 2 8 3 9 4 10 5 11 ...
$ Result  : Factor w/ 2 levels "2","1": 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 ...
$ Pool    : Factor w/ 1 level "High": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
- attr(*, "na.action")=Class 'omit'  Named int [1:45] 83 165 173 176 186 187 188 189 190 191 ...
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:45] "83" "165" "173" "176" ..
```

I would like to take the mean of x1$Result. when I do, I get this.

```
mean(x1$Result)
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(x1$Result) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

What can I do to get the mean? I think it has to do with the factor/levels.

Comment: Why are you taking the mean of a factor?  Is it supposed to be a factor?  Or should it be numeric? You might have to do `mean(as.numeric(as.character(x1$Result)))`, but it would first help to know why you're taking the mean of a factor.

Comment: I am just trying to find the mean of the column. I have never had this problem where I couldn't take the mean of numbers

Comment: Well the warning tells you that `x` can only be numeric or logical, otherwise you get NA.  So you'll need to convert.  Try my code above.

Comment: I did and it works. Thanks for your help. I will not this in my volume, thus not to make this mistake again. Cheers

Comment: Something important to know is do NOT go straight from factor to numeric (i.e. `as.numeric(x1$Result)`).  Use `as.character` in between when you convert like this, otherwise your results will probably be wrong..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments suggest a good solution, but the reason you have a factor in x1$result is probably of more interest.

When converting something to a data.frame strings are by default treated as factors rather than being coerced to numbers.  When you read in your data the x1$Pool column had a character type.  A matrix contains only one data type so your entire matrix was converted to a character matrix.  Converting this to a data.frame would result in each column becoming a factor rather than numeric.